# Using an if-else statement to assign a value to a variable, based on another variable's range

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a nutrient recommendation map using Python (in IDLE). I have many soil test points, and I used Kriging to interpolate them. For the sake of this post, the variable `field` is the raster with the nutrient levels within it.

The objective of my script is to assign a nutrient recommendation based on the existing levels of nutrients in a particular field. For instance, if an area in the `field` has a nutrient level between 0 and 5, I want to make a recommendation of 40.

I'm new to Python, so how can I write my if-else statement to accomplish this? Here is what I have tried:

```
if field == 0-5:
    recommendation = 50
elif field == 6-12:
    recommendation = 30
elif field == 13-25:
    recommendation = 15
```

Comment: `if 0 <= field <= 5` etc

Comment: `field == 0-5` is the same a `field == -5` - so you are comparing `field` with `-5` - is that what you really want to do?

Comment: `if field == 0-5:` Is just `if field == -5:`. You probably wanted a `range()` there and use `in`. `-` is "subtract", there is no concept of an _implicit_ range

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: Syntax questions do not involve the editor used to write the code or any IDE used to run it, so the latter should not be included in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below:

```
    if 0 <= field <= 5:
        recommendation = 50
    elif 5 < field <= 12:
        recommendation = 30
    elif 12 < field <= 25:
        recommendation = 15
    else:
        # DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

I assume it is possible for field to be a decimal? Not sure on the intended logic in your attempted solution, but I'm not sure if something like 5.6 would be handled by your attempt. Just something to be aware of.

To be clear, the do something else line is just there to indicate that you could put a statement here to handle inputs that are outside of the ranges in the if statements (print something, return something, raise an exception etc...). DO SOMETHING ELSE is not correct syntax for anything in Python.

Comment: Can I actually add the DO SOMETHING ELSE line, or is that just there to tell me to actually do something else?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant it to indicate that you may want to do something else to handle results outside of these ranges. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @ihb you can _literally_ _DO SOMETHING ELSE_ but you can't palm this off to python to decide what you _actually_ want to do in this case. You need to decide that.

Answer (score 3):

Python supports ranges pretty nicely with the following syntax

```
if 0 <= field <= 5:
    recommendation = 50
elif 6 <= field <= 12:
    recommendation = 30
elif 13 <= field <= 25:
    recommendation = 15
```